# JavaScript array filtering based on any combination of properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have array like this.

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Stephen',
  Team: {
    name: 'Lion',
    color: 'blue'
  },
  skills: ['allrounder', 'middleorder']
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Daniel',
  Team: {
    name: 'Panther',
    color: 'green'
  },
  skills: ['batsman', 'opener']
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Mark',
  Team: {
    name: 'Lion',
    color: 'blue'
  },
  skills: ['bowler', 'fielder']
}]
```

I am providing search facility on every field.

- Name: inputbox
- Team name: dopdownlist (to select team name)
- Team color: dropdownlist (to select team color)
- Skills: checkboxes

User can provide only `Name` field and click on Search , or can use multiple options like only skills or combination of any of input. 
What is best way to filter an array based on these conditions.
e.g.

```
myArr.filter(item => item.Name.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchData.name.toLowerCase())
                      && / || item.skills.include(searchData.skillsArr)
```

Expected output is based on any single or combination of input provided.

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide code snippet or explain attempts that failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a function using [**`filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like this:

- Check if there is value in `name` parameter. If yes, check if the `name` property of the array object [**`includes`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) the name
- If not, check for `teamName` and `color` parameter in a similar way
- Then check for an array of selected `skills`. Check if [**`some`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) of the skills are [`included`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in the object's `skills` array property

```js
const input=[{id:1,name:'Stephen',Team:{name:'Lion',color:'blue'},skills:['allrounder','middleorder']},{id:2,name:'Daniel',Team:{name:'Panther',color:'green'},skills:['batsman','opener']},{id:3,name:'Mark',Team:{name:'Lion',color:'blue'},skills:['bowler','fielder']}]

function filter(array, name, teamName, color, skills) {
  return array.filter(a =>
    (!name || a.name.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase())) &&
    (!teamName || a.Team.name.toLowerCase().includes(teamName.toLowerCase())) &&
    (!color || a.Team.color.toLowerCase().includes(color.toLowerCase())) &&
    (!skills || skills.length === 0 || skills.some(s => a.skills.includes(s)))
  )
}

console.log(filter(input, "Mark"))
console.log(filter(input, null, "Panther"))
console.log(filter(input, null, null, "blue", ["bowler"]))
```